# Measuring android WebApp launch time

Tags: java, android, web-applications

Is there any more decent method to check the time needed to launch my **WebApp** rather than taking system time at two points and calculate it manually?

The first (starting) point is where all the stuff starts - `onCreate()`method  (in *MainActivity.java*) and the final point is at the **index.html** file where content is generated by JavaScript code.